# Initializing multiple objects at once?

Tags: ruby, oop

So, I'm trying to initialize multiple objects and add them to a list. What I'm wanting to happen is by running `Market.new`, I want every item from the api added as an object. Below is the code I thought might work. But, it's adding the same object to the list 100x. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
def initialize
    data = JSON.parse(open(BASE_URL + "markets?vs_currency=usd").read)
    i = 0
    # looping until we hit the end of the list. adding them all as objects.
    while i < data.length
        @id = data[i]["id"].to_s
        @name = data[i]["name"].to_s
        @symbol = data[i]["symbol"].to_s
        @price = data[i]["current_price"].to_s
        @price_movement_24h = data[i]["price_change_percentage_24h"].to_s
        @market_cap = data[i]["market_cap"].to_s
        @@market << self
        i += 1
    end
end
```

This gives me the same object added to the @@market list 100x.

```
=> [#<Market:0x0000561b3f853f30
  @id="iostoken",
  @market_cap="43969067",
  @name="IOST",
  @price="0.0036523",
  @price_movement_24h="-0.76702",
  @symbol="iost">,
 #<Market:0x0000561b3f853f30
  @id="iostoken",
  @market_cap="43969067",
  @name="IOST",
  @price="0.0036523",
  @price_movement_24h="-0.76702",
  @symbol="iost">,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to start by saying this is very strange Ruby code and not something you'd typically do. That's not meant as an insult, just to say that Ruby devs tend to follow the same or similar guidelines on structuring objects and this chunk of code feels like it's ported from another language.

The issue you're seeing is due to the fact that within the `initialize` method you're not creating any new objects but instead updating the instance variables and pushing `self` into a class variable. `self` is referencing this instance directly which means the class variable array is filling up with references to the same object. If you're adamant on keeping the code the same then you should instead push a duplicate of your object after you've updated the instance variables.

```
@@market << self.dup
```

This creates a duplicate object that has a different memory address and reference.

If you're looking to write more idiomatic code you'd want to use multiple objects and not rely on class variables at all. If you're not interpolating a variable in a string use single quotes instead of double quotes. Keep object methods simple and focused on specific tasks. These are just a few things Ruby developers consider when writing code, but find what works best for you.

Take something like this for instance:

```
class Market
  attr_accessor :id, :name, :symbol, :price, :price_movement_24h, :market_cap

  def initialize(data = {})
    @id = data['id'].to_s
    @name = data['name'].to_s
    @symbol = data['symbol'].to_s
    @price = data['current_price'].to_s
    @price_movement_24h = data['price_change_percentage_24h'].to_s
    @market_cap = data['market_cap'].to_s
  end
end

class ImportService
  def self.from_api(url)
    response = JSON.parse(open(url).read) || []
    response.map { |data| Market.new(data) }
  end
end
```

You could then call this as such:

```
@market_data = ImportService.from_api(BASE_URL + 'markets?vs_currency=usd')
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of `@@market << self.dup` (assuming it were computed once in `initialize`). Suppose `c = C.new; c.instance_variable_set(:@id, 'cat')`, where `C` is the class. This would not affect the copy of `c` that was added to `@@market` in `initialize`. So what is the point of saving the copy of `c`?

Comment: Run the code and see for yourself. Without `dup` you're not creating a copy of c just pushing the reference to it. Check this example, try it both with and without the use of `dup`. You'll see that the output shows the same object memory space when not using dup. https://pastebin.com/ujLjDKi1

Answer (score 1):

When adding `self` to the `@@market`, you should change the code to this

```
@@market << self.dup
```

However, I don't think it's a good practice to use a class variable here and add `self` to init an array of object. Instead, you should create a new class (for example `MarketImporter`)

```
class Market
  attr_accessor :id, :name, :symbol, :price, :price_movement_24h, :market_cap

  def initialize(data = {})
    @id = data["id"].to_s
    @name = data["name"].to_s
    @symbol = data["symbol"].to_s
    @price = data["current_price"].to_s
    @price_movement_24h = data["price_change_percentage_24h"].to_s
    @market_cap = data["market_cap"].to_s
  end
end

class MarketImporter
  attr_accessor :markets

  def initialize
    data = JSON.parse(open(BASE_URL + "markets?vs_currency=usd").read)
    @markets = data.collect { |item| Market.new(item) }
  end
end
```

Then you can init the collection by

```
MarketImporter.new
```

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. But, this is for a class and the project requirements ask to use certain things, so I was trying to do it within those constraints. The .dup worked perfectly. And thank you for the suggestion, that makes more sense.

Comment: Why do you suggest changing `@@market << self` to `@@market << self.dup` (which is the same as `@@market << dup`)? If you're afraid that `@@market = "cat"` (with `@@market << self`) will change `self` you can rest easy; `self` cannot be changed directly.